# python multiple conditions at the same time

Tags: python, loops

I am  basic user with python 2.7 .my query is this

```
x = raw_input(...:)

if len(x) != 6

    re enter x

if x(1:2) < 0 or x(1:2) > 20

    re enter x 

if x(1:2) < 0 or x(1:2) > 20

    re enter x
```

The problem with the above process is that it checks the conditions one by one. For example if at the 3rd `if` I enter 4 digits instead of 6 its still an error but does not display the right error.

I tried using a while loopat the beginning under which the if statements are present, but thesame problem occurs: it catches the error but not the right error message.

I would really appreciate any help on this. What I want is that regardless of where I re-enter `x` it should check all if-statements.

Comment: `x(1:2)` doesn't look like valid syntax ... Am I missing something?  usually we can give you the best help if you post actual code that we can run and see the behaviors you describe.

Comment: Please try to make code that executes before posting here so YOU can see what happens instead of asking us to predict it for you.

Comment: im sorry if i was a little blunt.

Comment: import string

x = raw_input("enter the number: ")

a =str(x)

if len(x) != 6:

    input= raw_input("the no has to have 6 digits: ")

if (a[0:2]<'1') or (a[0:2]>'12'):

   input= raw_input("the first 2 digits must be 1-12: ")    

if (a[3:5]<'1') or (a[3:5]>'35'):

    input= raw_input("the middle 2 digits must be 1-35: ")    

print 'hello'

Comment: im going to repost this sorry

Comment: Did you mean `x[1:2]`?  By the way, `raw_input()` returns a string, `0` is an `int`.  It is not correct to compare these types, you should convert one so it is the same type as the other.

Answer (score 2):

From the very obfusuicated request I could extract only 4 things;

You want:

1. An input x that should be re-prompted until x satisfies conditions.
2. length of x should be different than 6?
3. if x is let's say 123456, you want 2 to be greater than 0 and less than 20?

   ```
   while True: #This is a while loop. True could be replaced with a boolean. But for now, we will keep it True to run until break. 
       x=raw_input() #Get some input
       if len(x) != 6 or 0<x[1:2]<20: #I used or because I don't know if you want both to be True, or 1 to be True, in order for the input to be invalid. Switch to and for both.      
           print "wrong please try again" 
           continue #Continue takes the code back to the beginning where we prompted for input. 
       else: #If the else is not satisfied...
           break #Break out of the loop and stock asking for input.
   ```

A few things you should learn from your own code:

```
x = raw_input(...:)

if len(x)!=6 #This one I understand, but still, should use while loop.

 re enter x #Unneccesary if you switch to while loop and use keyword continue. 

if x(1:2)<0 or x(1:2)>20 #x(1:2) I am guessing you want to slice, you need [] not ()

re enter x #Unneccesary if you switch to while loop and use keyword continue.

if x(1:2)<0 or x(1:2)>20 #Why do you even have this here? Same as line above

re enter x  #Unneccesary if you switch to while loop and use keyword continue.

#Did you want your conditions to BOTH be True and reenter, or only 1? 
#This is important for boolean logic. 
#This is what determines if you will use AND or OR boolean operators.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `if...else` code:

```
if condition_1:
    ...do something...
elif condition 2:
    ...do something else...
else:
    ...do something else again...
```

You'll have to check for those condition after everytime the user inputs something.

Also, you could use a variable to detect for valir input:

```
valid = False
while valid == False:
    valid = True
    input = raw_input()
    if error_condition:
        valid = False
        ...do_something...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `any`:

```
while True:
    x = raw_input(prompt)
    if any([len(x) != 6, x[1:2] < 0,  x[1:2] > 20]):
        continue
    break
```